# How to convert undefined/propriatary file with ImageMagick?

Tags: macos, terminal, imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to execute this command on MacOS:

```
convert -depth 16 -size 210x274 SCRSHOT5 \( -clone -evaluate RightShift 11 -evaluate And 31 -evaluate LeftShift 11 \) \( -clone 0 -evaluate RightShift 5 -evaluate And 63 -evaluate LeftShift 10 \) \( -clone 0 -evaluate And 31 -evaluate LeftShift 11\) -delete 0 -combine out.png
```

The file is undefined (weird screenshot of weird display) and I do not know what it is. But I am 100% sure that it is convertible to PNG.

Getting these error messages:

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/746.

convert: image sequence is required `+clone' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1017.
```

Tried different syntax but also didn't work. File name before \

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell **ImageMagick** what sort of data it is, either greyscale, RGB or similar.

You can do that explicitly via the extension if your file has one (or you add one):

```
magick -depth 16 -size 210x274 SCRSHOT5.rgb ...

magick -depth 16 -size 210x274 SCRSHOT5.gray ...
```

or implicitly via a prefix - which doesn't require you to change your filename:

```
magick -depth 16 -size 210x274 RGB:SCRSHOT5 ...

magick -depth 16 -size 210x274 GRAY:SCRSHOT5...
```

---

As you appear to be unpacking 4 channels (RGBA) from 16-bit integers, you will need to tell **ImageMagick** it is greyscale data in order to read a single 16-bit value to make each pixel.

---

You should check the size of your file is 210 * 274 * 2 bytes in size.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using GRAY: worked.